# Any way to determine when the last listboxitem comes into view?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am new to windows phone and coming from an ios background. My question is, how can i programmatically determine when the last listboxitem comes into view? I am currently using a custom listboxitem and programmatically adding each item.

Comment: FWIW, the LongListSelector is preferred over ListBox in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Why do you need to know if last item is visible?  Are you planning on dynamically loading more data, say from a service?

Comment: exactly, just to populate more items from json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most scenarios on Windows Phone 8 it's better to use the `LongListSelector` instead of the `ListBox` control.

Instead of loading all the items at once, the LongListSelector virtualizes its content, only loading data as needed to show in its viewport.

The ItemRealized event fires when a new item is assigned a UI container (realized).  Use this event to determine if you are close to the end of the items in the datasource, then load more data.

**XAML**

```xml
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name='longListFlights'
                        ItemsSource='{Binding}'
                        ItemRealized='longListFlights_ItemRealized'
                        Height='205'
                        Margin='20'>
  <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

      <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'>
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding FlightNumber}'
                     Foreground='Yellow' />

        <TextBlock Text='{Binding TimeStamp}'
                     Margin='20,0,0,0' />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

**CODE**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    private ObservableCollection<Flight> _flights = 
                         new ObservableCollection<Flight>();
    private bool _isLoadingData;

    public MainPage() {
      InitializeComponent();

      AddFlights(60);
      this.DataContext = _flights;
    }

    private void AddFlights(int numberFlightsToAdd) {
      _isLoadingData = true;
      int max = _flights.Count + numberFlightsToAdd;
      for (int i = _flights.Count; i < max; i++)
      {
        _flights.Add(new Flight { FlightNumber = string.Format("AB-{0:D3}", i),
                                  TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });
      }
      _isLoadingData = false;
    }

    private void longListFlights_ItemRealized(object sender, 
                                              ItemRealizationEventArgs e) {

      Flight flight = e.Container.Content as Flight;
       if (flight != null)
      {
        if (!_isLoadingData)
        {
          // get current count of data-source
          int count = _flights.Count;

          // get index of item being realized (placed in container)
          int index = _flights.IndexOf(flight);

          // if we are close to the end, load more data
          if (count - index <= 5)
          {
            AddFlights(10);
          }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(flight.FlightNumber);
      }
    }
  }

  internal class Flight {

    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Walt! I'll accept this answer since it is straight to the point and should help others in the future.